# Sigma notation for repeated integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

If we use repeated integration by parts, for example
$$I= \int_0^\pi f(x)\sin x\,dx= \Big[-f(x)\cos x\Big]_{x=0}^{x=\pi}-\Big[-f'(x) \sin x \Big]_{x=0}^{x=\pi} + \cdots \pm \Big[ f^{(2n)}(x) \cos x \Big]_{x=0}^{x=\pi} \pm \int_0^\pi f^{(2n+1)}(x)\cos x\,dx,$$
can $I$ be written more compactly using the sigma notation? I thought of
$$I=-\sum_{m=0}^{2n} \Big[f^{(m)}(x)\sin ^{(m+1)}x\Big]_{x=0}^{x=\pi}+\int_0^\pi f^{(2n+1)}(x)\sin ^{(2n)}x\, dx,$$
though I'm not sure if it's correct.

Comment: Is $f(x)$ unknown$?$ If not then it's easy enough to get the definite integral.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{x^n(a-bx)^n}{n!}$, I know how to evaluate that integral, but I was curious if the process of repeated integration by parts can be written more compactly.

Comment: "Tabular method" ... Google "integration by parts tabular" to see how others have done this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can prove by induction that$$\int_a^buv^{(n)}dx=\left[\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(-1)^ju^{(j)}v^{(n-1-j)}\right]+(-1)^n\int_a^bu^{(n)}vdx.$$The case $n=0$ is trivial, the case $n=1$ is just ordinary integration by parts, and for the inductive step from $n=k$ to $n=k+1$ use the inductive hypothesis with $v^\prime$ in place of $v$:$$\begin{align}\int_a^buv^{(k+1)}dx&=\left[\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(-1)^ju^{(j)}v^{(k-j)}\right]+(-1)^k\int_a^bu^{(k)}v^\prime dx\\&=\left[\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^ju^{(j)}v^{(k-j)}\right]+(-1)^{k+1}\int_a^bu^{(k+1)}vdx.\end{align}$$You can rewrite $\int_a^bf(x)\sin xdx$ with this, but you'd need to consider $4$ cases separately, as $\sin x$ is the $n$th derivative of any of $4$ functions. A slight variant is to write$$\begin{align}\int_a^bf(x)\sin xdx&=\frac{1}{2i}\int_a^bf(x)(\exp ix-\exp -ix)dx\\&=\frac{1}{2i}\bigg[\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(-1)^jf^{(j)}(x)(i^{-j-1}\exp ix+i^{j-1}\exp -ix)\\&+(-1)^n\int_a^bf^{(n)}(x)(i^{-n}\exp ix-i^n\exp -ix)dx\bigg].\end{align}$$